# Is there an opensource Airline Seat Map API?

Tags: api

Are there any Seat Map API that's available on the market? We had a crude XML return
from a webservice that gives out available and occupied plane seats. On an ideal scenario, what I thought would be just to map out the return dataset with the Seat Map API and it would give me out a pretty representation (GUI) that we could use.

I searched the net but so far, there's seatguru (seatguru.com) but it doesn't have an API.
It would be hell if I do this from scratch as there are tons of airplane types and it varies from airline to airline.

Answer (score 4):

Hey So after doing allot of searching and thinking about scraping or copy pasting or requesting from each airline directly their seat maps i found one source. lol go figure. Sabre Dev Studios has a new api Take a look at it here https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/seat_map